# Kotlin delay won't fire on long delays

Tags: android, kotlin, delay, kotlin-coroutines

So I have 2 main places I have that I use a delay. Both are designed as loops, the first is a 5 second delay, and the second is an hour. They are along the lines of this:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    delay(5000)
    // Execute code
}
```

This code runs in the background, doesn't matter if the app is open or closed or if the phone is locked. The 5 second delay like here works fine, however, the 1hr one doesn't seem to work (I had it set at 60 seconds to test and it worked fine, just updated the number to an hour and it stopped working).

Once I load the app again as soon as it opens it seems to fire, but this may be after 2hrs or so. I don't mind if its not exactly an hr, or even runs on next unlock of the phone, but needs to happen in the background without opening the app.

From research I have seen this could be when the phone goes into a "deep sleep", so I made sure the app had unrestricted battery usage.

How can I get a long delay that will still fire while ever the phone is on? (If the phone is rebooted on boot complete this function starts again, so that's fine)

Comment: Workmanager will be best solution to execute task in this situation as it will asure that task will executed so would like to suggest to use workmanager . Use coroutine to execute heavy tasks only not app background tasks

Comment: Never use coroutines for stuff you want to happen while your app is off-screen. It simply won’t work because your app execution is paused at some point. Exception would be a coroutine inside a foreground service.

Comment: Ok, I could try do a periodic work request in workmanager. I tried alarm manager but it didn't work. With workmanager, is it possible to change something in the interface (so that if the app is opened can see the last time it was run)? If I have a button to launch the periodic work request, is pressing the button again going to wipe the old schedule and start a new one? Will a schedule continue after a phone reboot?